# Listing items on the Java classpath from the current project only

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Java project with a large classpath - many of the items are imported from different .jar files that have been added as dependencies (via Maven).

I'm looking for a programmatic way to list all the items on the classpath that come from the current project, i.e. **excluding** all the imported classpath items from other libraries and the Java runtime environment itself.

I need to do this at runtime, i.e. it should work off the actual current classpath.

Is there a good way to do this, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this unless you create your own metadata.

To the JVM, there is no distinction between items in the classpath. A jar is a jar is a jar.

You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) to write out a list of the dependencies that are local, and not transitive, and write that into a file, and put that file in your application.

Comment: OK annoying but thanks.... is there even a concept of the "current jar" that can be identified?